# Counting the number of occurences of a string inside a string

Tags: java, recursion, word-frequency

Here is  my attempt at this method.

> Count the number of co-occurrances of a non-empty sub-string sub within the string str E.g.
>
> numOccurances("dogmonkeydog","dog") will return 2
>
> numOccurances("dogmonkeydog","mon") will return 1
>
> numOccurances("dogmonkeydog","cow") will return 0

```
public static int numOccurrences(String str, String sub) {
    int result = 0;
    int pos = str.indexOf(sub);
    if (pos == -1){
        return result;
    }
    if (sub.length() > str.length()){
        return result;
    }
    if ((str.substring(0, sub.length())).equals(sub)){
        result++;
        String st = str.substring(pos);
        return result + numOccurrences(st, sub); //Line 87
    }
    else{
        String st = str.substring(sub.length());
        return result + numOccurrences(st, sub);
    }
}
```

I get this failure for all tests where the result > 0

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.String.indexOf(String.java:1718)
    at java.lang.String.indexOf(String.java:1698)
    at eecs2030.lab6.RecursiveTasks.numOccurrences(RecursiveTasks.java:77)
    at eecs2030.lab6.RecursiveTasks.numOccurrences(RecursiveTasks.java:87)
```

I'm unsure as to why my code never reaches its base case, any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: You have an infinite recursion. You need to debug to understand why it happens.

Comment: Why are you using recursion to solve an iterative problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an school assignment. So, I'll not give you the answer directly.

In the following snippet,

```
result++;
String st = str.substring(pos);
return result + numOccurrences(st, sub); //Line 87
```

the place where you are creating `st` is problematic. If `str` begins with the value contained in `sub`, then `str` will be equal to `st`. So, the call to `numOccurrences` will be same as your original call and so your recursion will not terminate.

Analyze what needs to be passed to `str.substring` in the above snippet.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! I read through where you suggested and found the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The third if condition in  your method is not needed.

```
 if ((str.substring(0, sub.length())).equals(sub))
```

you can simply define the third case as

```
 if(pos>=0)
  {
  result++;
  String newstr = str.substring(pos + sub.length());
  return numOccurrences(newstr,sub);
  }
```

since, if the substring is find ,the pos variable will be initialised by starting index of substring, you can increment result here.

then recursively call numOccurences() method on the rest of the string.
and also declare variable result outside of the method.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 class SubString
 {
 String user,subUser;
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
 int num;
 static  int result = 0;
 int numOccurrences(String str, String sub) {

  int pos = str.indexOf(sub);
  if (pos == -1){
    return result;
 }
 if (sub.length() > str.length()){
    return result;
  }
  else if(pos >= 0)
  {
   result++;
   String newstr = str.substring(pos + sub.length());
   return numOccurrences(newstr,sub);
   }
 return result;

 }

//constructor
 SubString()
 {
   try{
   System.out.println("Enter string :");
   user=sc.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter the substring: ");
   subUser=sc.nextLine();
   num = numOccurrences(user,subUser);
   System.out.println(num);
  }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
    System.out.println(e);
   } 

 }
 public static void main(String...a)
{
 new SubString();
 }
 }
```

`

Answer (score 1):

```
1 : public static int numOccurrences(String str, String sub) {
2 :    int result = 0;
3 :    int pos = str.indexOf(sub);
4 :    if (pos == -1){
5 :        return result;
6 :    }
7 :    if (sub.length() > str.length()){
8 :        return result;
9 :    }
10:    if ((str.substring(0, sub.length())).equals(sub)){
11:        result++;
12:        String st = str.substring(pos);
13:        return result + numOccurrences(st, sub); 
14:    }
15:    else{
16:        String st = str.substring(sub.length());
17:        return result + numOccurrences(st, sub);
18:    }
19:}
```

*Line 10 -* You are not extracting the substring of the given `sub` string parameter in the actual string `str`.
*Line 12 -* You are almost there in discarding the current substring for the next call but you are including the string too.
          Example: **monstrfri** -> with substring **str** will result in **strfri** rather than **fri**

If you prefer to change your logic, you can get this through a simple while loop
pos is index of substring

```
counter is 0
while pos!=-1
    increment the counter
    trim the current substring found
    extract the next position
    and continue while
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      public static int findOcc(String str,String sub){
        int count =0;
        int occurence = 0;
        char strArray [] = str.toCharArray();
        char subArray [] = sub.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++){
            if(strArray[i]==subArray[0]){
              for(int j=0,k=i;j<subArray.length && k < strArray.length 
              ;j++,k++){
                        if(strArray[k]==subArray[j]){
                          count++;
                        }
                       }
                       if(count == subArray.length){
                          occurence++;
                 }
                 count =0;
              }
         }
      return occurence;
    }
```

Comment: Instead of recursion , you can do like this.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however for this we were asked to use recursion in our approach.